# Nominatim make error "Missing input file"

Tags: postgresql, maps, freebsd, nominatim

I'm trying to install NOMINATIM, under the  [instruction](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#First_Installation)

point first installation instructions for the team of Make getting following error:

```
Making all in osm2pgsql
/usr/local/bin/protoc-c --proto_path=protobuf --c_out=.
Missing input file.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/ftpmpnik/mapnikdata/Nominatim-2.0.1/osm2pgsql.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/ftpmpnik/mapnikdata/Nominatim-2.0.1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you probably need to use GNU make (gmake); lots of software isn't properly tested with other make flavours.

If that's not the case please supply details - compiler and make version, configure/autoconf/automake versions if you're using them, etc.